# Unity Crashes Because of For Statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position, transform

After I added this one for statement, Unity crashes, I've reopened and reran it several times, but it still crashes. Here is the for statement:

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    player.transform.position += Vector3.right * -1;
    i = 0;
}
```

Comment: All infinite loops crash unity. Why would you want to do this

Comment: @BugFinder The reason I did it was because I thought that was the only method to have a repeating function that would have a delay of some sort. What is a better method?

Comment: No. That will not give the slightest delay it just constantly will do the first thing and never ever stop. Look up coroutines. They allow to yield and basically pause them for a while without the whole death of unity.  If you want it to constantly run you can do that but there are many other ways to achieve a perpetual loop without the infinite loop of a snake eating its tail. You can just do while true; something; yield some seconds and it will do that eith seconds between each loop if you use coroutines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code results in an infinite loop. If you want to have a repeating function with a delay, you can use [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html). The [YieldInstruction](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/YieldInstruction.html) (`yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime)` in the unity document example) determine the amount of time you wish to wait. The sample code in the document prints infinitely with a 2 second delay; however, rewriting the condition of the `while` loop is one of the ways that helps you determine when a coroutine ends.

Another way to acheive it is using [async/await](https://www.raywenderlich.com/26799311-introduction-to-asynchronous-programming-in-unity). However, the instructions you can use for await are not as rich as yield instructions. Moreover, the last time I checked, a while true code with a print statment, keeps printing even when unity is not in play mode anymore.

Comment: this does work. But I did find I better solution for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is running infinitely. On each iteration you set your counter variable back to 0, hence it never stops and keeps decrementing your player position. Have you tried forcing the loop to quit at one point to see if your program still crashes?

Comment: The issue is I want it to run infinitely. Again, I am a beginner, so if there is a better way to handle a repeating function that has a delay, I would be pleased if you told me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course you program crashes, you have an infinite loop due to always resetting

```
i = 0;
```

which basically makes it equivalent to

```
while(true)
{
    // move
}
```

since you never exit this loop you never allow Unity to move on in its execution -> The app and the entire Unity editor which runs in the same single Unity main thread completely freezes.

---

Since you say you want this to happen infinitely anyway, what you rather want is move this into [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) which is called **once every frame** and then use [`Tim.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) to convert your fixed `value per frame` into a `value per second`

```
// Speed in Units per second
// adjust this via the Inspector
[SerializeField] private float speed = 1;

private void Update()
{
    player.transform.position += Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```